# Mysql query join two tables with same value?

Tags: php, mysql

I have this kind of query, i will try to make it so simple to understand, he query is much bigger :)

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM Artist";
$query2= "SELECT * FROM News";
```

All table structure in Artist and in News is the same rows etc

**ID
Title
Posts**

Is it possible to join this two queries in one, and do something like shuffle ($query);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select ID, Title, Posts from Artist, 'Artist' as Type
union all
select ID, Title, Posts from News, 'News' as Type
```

Comment: Do i must name all rows? Can I use just *

Comment: @RedFilter can you explain a bit how it works, or post a link to more info?

Comment: @Sébastien UNION ALL paste result off query1 together with result off query2 and leaving duplicates in the end result... UNION without ALL would remove duplicates

Comment: Ok, i was thinking about accepting answer, ok I will accept then this one :)